# Number of query values and destinations fields are not the same

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

This is the function for automatically stored value to TotalAmt_tx.Text..

```
   void TotalAmount()
            {
                .
                .
                .
                .
                TotalAmt_tx.Text = Total.ToString("00.00");
                .
                .
                .
                catch { }
            }
```

Save button code :[here the image of my forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9rlx.jpg)

```
private void Save_bt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Purchase Table
            {
                string insertPur = "Insert into Purchase (Invoice,VendorName,PurchaseDate,TotalAmt) values ("+Invoice_tx.Text+"," +
                    "'"+VendorName_cb.Text+"','"+PurchaseDate_dt.Value.Date.ToString()+"',"+TotalAmt_tx.Text+" )";

                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(insertPur, conn);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);                
            }

            //Purchase Item Table
            for (int i = 0; i < metroGrid1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string insertPur = "Insert into PurchaseItem (Invoice, PId, Product, Qty, Rate, Amount) values (" + Invoice_tx.Text + "," +
                    ""+metroGrid1.Rows[i].Cells["PId"].Value.ToString()+ ",'" + metroGrid1.Rows[i].Cells["Product"].Value.ToString() + "'," +
                    "" + metroGrid1.Rows[i].Cells["Qty"].Value.ToString() + "," + metroGrid1.Rows[i].Cells["Rate"].Value.ToString() + "," +
                    "" + metroGrid1.Rows[i].Cells["Amount"].Value.ToString() + ")";

                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(insertPur, conn);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved!!");
```

The problems show up because this

> TotalAmt_tx.Text = Total.ToString("00.00")

What should I do, to solve it??
I've try follow some tutorial about formatting string but nothings works.
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try to use [OleDbParameter Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2), because if one of the values you combine to your query string has the `,` character it will mess-up you query (for example a number in the following format `1,000`).

Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you sir, that's a great help. But, the problem show up because of format value of my TotalAmt._tx.Text isn't match with the query. So, what should I do??

Comment: Cause, I want to display TotalAmt_tx from double to string format. Looks like this : 1000 ----> 1000.00 …. but always show this error.

Comment: Then just transform it back before you use it in the query.

Answer (score 0):

You should always stick to parameterized queries to avoid SQL Injection. It also helps in avoiding mistakes like missing a "'"

```
using (OleDbConnection connection =new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
 var query = "Insert into Purchase (Invoice,VendorName,PurchaseDate,TotalAmt) values (@invoice,@vendor,@purchasedate,@amt)";
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(queryString, connection);


 adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@invoic", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Invoice_tx.Text);
 adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@vendor", OleDbType.VarChar,100).Value = VendorName_cb.Text;
 adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@invoic", OleDbType.Date).Value = PurchaseDate_dt.Value.Date; // I do not know what PurchaseDate_dt.Value.Date  type is, so I leave it to you to convert to approapriate type
 adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@CategoryName", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(TotalAmt_tx.Text);

 connection.Open();
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 adapter.Fill(ds);
}
```